# ALT+TAB doesn't work in remote desktop sessions

Tags: mojave, remote-desktop

For some reason, the <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> key combination no longer functions on Windows via MRD.  This worked only a week ago.

Oddly, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> does work to switch applications, but releasing the keys does not activate the window (nor does <kbd>Enter</kbd> or any other key).

Another oddity, some application will remain in focus (they are not maximized) even when another application is chosen from the taskbar.

Versions:

- OS X: 10.14.3 (Mojave)
- Microsoft Remote Desktop: 10.2.11
- Windows: Enterprise v7 sp1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting windows fixed the problem.